# How to add battery_cost_change multiple time with counter value in firebase in same user Message Which is LM2JKCacawaW7tlK4yK

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

is it possible to insert battery_cost_change: field multiple time with counter value in firebase in same user Message Which is LM2JKCacawaW7tlK4yK. like battery_cost_change1: ,battery_cost_change2:,battery_cost_change3: and so on And how these fields will be retrieve in android programmatically[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhcxi.png)

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to consider the db structure for `battery_cost_changes` to hold multiple instances of `battery_cost_change` object.
Everytime you add a new `battery_cost_change` - you can **push** the object into the path `.../LM2JKCacawaW7tlK4yK/battery_cost_changes`. `<pushId>` is the random ID Firebase generates, when an object is pushed/added into the node.

```
{ LM2JKCacawaW7tlK4yK: {
   ....
   battery_cost_changes: {
          <pushId>: {
            battery_cost_change: 6
          },
          <pushId>: {
            battery_cost_change: 3
          }
   }
   ....
}
```

While retrieving the values, you can read the path `.../LM2JKCacawaW7tlK4yK/battery_cost_changes` and observe the values for an **array** of `battery_change_cost` objects. Please share more details, to explore a better or more suitable answer. However, I feel this is a generic idea to store multiple values under a node.